# Shapely geometry intersection - in which cases a line string and polygon would intersect?

Tags: shapely

[Attached image shows the LineString or rather LineRing and a polygon. I expect them to intersect but they don not as per shapely intersects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLOzd.png)I have two geometries which i expected to intersect. But they do not. One is a line string (which forms a ring ) and other a little square polygon that is totally inside the line string. It does not touch any of the line string points. 
Looking at shapely intersection documentation, i expected them to intersect, but they don;t.

```
geom1 = LINESTRING (-68.41186519999999 -19.429039, -68.35556029999999 -19.5293773, -68.24775699999999 -19.5717596, -68.1444168 -19.6110584, -68.0488014 -19.5375473, -67.87353520000001 -19.5287301, -67.75165560000001 -19.4610893, -67.67972949999999 -19.4220778, -67.7508831 -19.389615, -67.9814672 -19.3241436, -68.0075276 -19.2455493, -67.9786563 -19.1669174, -68.0376756 -19.0532041, -68.10563740000001 -19.1637403, -68.14785809999999 -19.1696967, -68.1900787 -19.1185707, -68.25668330000001 -19.1775984, -68.3349609 -19.1970534, -68.3638 -19.2152094, -68.4386444 -19.2709616, -68.44757079999999 -19.3370618, -68.41186519999999 -19.429039)

Geom2 = tile_polygon_geom = MULTIPOLYGON (((-68.203125 -19.331878, -68.203125 -19.352611, -68.181152 -19.352611, -68.181152 -19.331878, -68.203125 -19.331878)))
```

If i edit the LINESTRING to a polygon - kept the same points, just changed the test LINESTRING to POLYGON i see the outer and inner polygon intersect.

```
("POLYGON((-68.41186519999999 -19.429039, -68.35556029999999 -19.5293773, -68.24775699999999 -19.5717596, -68.1444168 -19.6110584, -68.0488014 -19.5375473, -67.87353520000001 -19.5287301, -67.75165560000001 -19.4610893, -67.67972949999999 -19.4220778, -67.7508831 -19.389615, -67.9814672 -19.3241436, -68.0075276 -19.2455493, -67.9786563 -19.1669174, -68.0376756 -19.0532041, -68.10563740000001 -19.1637403, -68.14785809999999 -19.1696967, -68.1900787 -19.1185707, -68.25668330000001 -19.1775984, -68.3349609 -19.1970534, -68.3638 -19.2152094, -68.4386444 -19.2709616, -68.44757079999999 -19.3370618, -68.41186519999999 -19.429039))”)
```

i.e. the code The following code prints "geometries intersect"

```
geometry1 =  wktloads ("POLYGON((-68.41186519999999 -19.429039, -68.35556029999999 -19.5293773, -68.24775699999999 -19.5717596, -68.1444168 -19.6110584, -68.0488014 -19.5375473, -67.87353520000001 -19.5287301, -67.75165560000001 -19.4610893, -67.67972949999999 -19.4220778, -67.7508831 -19.389615, -67.9814672 -19.3241436, -68.0075276 -19.2455493, -67.9786563 -19.1669174, -68.0376756 -19.0532041, -68.10563740000001 -19.1637403, -68.14785809999999 -19.1696967, -68.1900787 -19.1185707, -68.25668330000001 -19.1775984, -68.3349609 -19.1970534, -68.3638 -19.2152094, -68.4386444 -19.2709616, -68.44757079999999 -19.3370618, -68.41186519999999 -19.429039))”)

gepmetry2 = wktloads ( "MULTIPOLYGON (((-68.203125 -19.331878, -68.203125 -19.352611, -68.181152 -19.352611, -68.181152 -19.331878, -68.203125 -19.331878)))")

if geometry1.intersects(gepmetry2):
    self.logger.info("geometries intersect")
else:
    self.logger.info("geometries do not intersect")
```

Can someone explain what would be intersection of LINESTRING and a polygon if:
1) polygon lines and the line string cross at some point
2) polygon is enclosed within a line string, no points touching
3) Linestring is fully enclosed within the polygon, no points touching

As i mentioned, I am expecting #2 to return true but it does not.

Documentation I am referring to: http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html

object.intersects(other)
Returns True if the boundary and interior of the object intersect in any way with those of the other.

This predicate is equivalent to the OR-ing of contains(), crosses(), equals(), touches(), and within().

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`geom1` and `Geom2` are not validly constructed shapely geometry.

If you adjust your code to resemble the approach you take with `geometry1` and `gepmetry2`, then it will work:

```
from shapely import geometry, wkt

linestring =  wkt.loads ("LINESTRING(-68.41186519999999 -19.429039, -68.35556029999999 -19.5293773, -68.24775699999999 -19.5717596, -68.1444168 -19.6110584, -68.0488014 -19.5375473, -67.87353520000001 -19.5287301, -67.75165560000001 -19.4610893, -67.67972949999999 -19.4220778, -67.7508831 -19.389615, -67.9814672 -19.3241436, -68.0075276 -19.2455493, -67.9786563 -19.1669174, -68.0376756 -19.0532041, -68.10563740000001 -19.1637403, -68.14785809999999 -19.1696967, -68.1900787 -19.1185707, -68.25668330000001 -19.1775984, -68.3349609 -19.1970534, -68.3638 -19.2152094, -68.4386444 -19.2709616, -68.44757079999999 -19.3370618, -68.41186519999999 -19.429039)")

poly1 =  wkt.loads ("POLYGON((-68.41186519999999 -19.429039, -68.35556029999999 -19.5293773, -68.24775699999999 -19.5717596, -68.1444168 -19.6110584, -68.0488014 -19.5375473, -67.87353520000001 -19.5287301, -67.75165560000001 -19.4610893, -67.67972949999999 -19.4220778, -67.7508831 -19.389615, -67.9814672 -19.3241436, -68.0075276 -19.2455493, -67.9786563 -19.1669174, -68.0376756 -19.0532041, -68.10563740000001 -19.1637403, -68.14785809999999 -19.1696967, -68.1900787 -19.1185707, -68.25668330000001 -19.1775984, -68.3349609 -19.1970534, -68.3638 -19.2152094, -68.4386444 -19.2709616, -68.44757079999999 -19.3370618, -68.41186519999999 -19.429039))")

if poly1.intersects(linestring):
    print("linestring intersects") 
else:
    print("linestring does not intersect")

poly2 = wkt.loads ("MULTIPOLYGON (((-68.203125 -19.331878, -68.203125
-19.352611, -68.181152 -19.352611, -68.181152 -19.331878, -68.203125 -19.331878)))")

if poly1.intersects(poly2):
    print("polys intersect") 
else:
    print("polys do not intersect")
```